# NDSolve involves previous time step value

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, event-detection

I am trying to use NDSolve to solve problems involve previous time step value. For example, instead of using the working code below:

```
    NDSolve[{x'[t] == a[t] Sin[t], x[0] == 0, a[0] == 1, 
           WhenEvent[Sin[t] == 0, a[t] -> -a[t]]}, x, {t, 0, 20} , 
          DiscreteVariables -> {a}, StartingStepSize -> 0.1, Method -> {"FixedStep", 
  Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 4, 
    "Coefficients" -> ClassicalRK4Coefficients}}];
```

how i wish i could replace the WhenEvent above with

```
WhenEvent[x[t]-x[t-0.1] < 0, a[t] -> -a[t]]
```

(to note x[t] is current value and x[t-0.1] is previous value). I have no idea how to apply it, anyone can enlighten me?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question can be solved by storing the old value of `x` as an additional discrete variable.

```
s = Flatten@NDSolve[{x'[t] == a[t] Sin[t], x[0] == 0, a[0] == 1, tem[0] == 0, 
    WhenEvent[Mod[t, .1] == 0, {If[x[t] - tem[t] < 0, a[t] -> -a[t]], tem[t] -> x[t]}]}, 
    {x, a}, {t, 0, 20}, DiscreteVariables -> {a, tem}, StartingStepSize -> 0.1, 
  Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}}];

Plot[x[t] /. s, {t, 0, 20}, AxesLabel -> {t, x}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[a[t] /. s, {t, 0, 20}, AxesLabel -> {t, a}]
```

[image]

Note that this method works equally well for non-constant time-steps.

Comment: Thank you very much. You helped me a lot. I appreciated it.